# Working with a corrupted GIF

Tags: image, imagemagick, photoshop, gif, corruption

I'm trying to manipulate an image generated by the MapQuest traffic API. [Here's an example](http://www.mapquestapi.com/traffic/v2/flow?key=Fmjtd%7Cluub2d0an1,7g=o5-9u2a9w&mapLat=41.884151&mapLng=-87.632408&mapHeight=800&mapWidth=800&mapScale=108335). The image file that page generates appears to be corrupted (but not consistently). I can never edit it with ImageMagick, GIFLIB, PIL, or Photoshop. But sometimes the same file displays just fine in Chrome and Firefox.

(1) Is it possible to fix the corrupted file? The fact that a browser can display it suggests that it's salvageable.

(2) Why would a browser recognize the image when ImageMagick, etc. can't?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this image was not saved properly and some visual info was lost. Fortunately it's always possible to solve such problem with non-standard approach :) I just placed this image into Adobe Illustrator and saved it as PNG. You can download it here:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/oschyb4jfzlaw7a/flow2.png

That's it :) Hope this helps.

-- Alex

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I want to be able to work with the image programmatically, so Illustrator won't work.

Comment: I think it's barely possible because it seems that the MapQuest generates the images with some errors inside GIFs. That's why you can't open it as usual image in image editor. Maybe you can change an image format, to PNG or JPG for example? This can solve this issue.